# Send iOS push notification without port 2195

Tags: php, ios, notifications, push

This question has been asked before, but in the answer, the code doesn't work.

How can I send iOS push notifications from PHP without using port 2195, which is blocked on my host (one.com)

I have tried this code:

```
$url = 'https://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';
$cert = 'ck.pem';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'password_hidden_on_stack_overflow');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"device_tokens": ["458e5939b2xxxxxxxxxxx3"], "aps": {"alert": "test message one!"}}');

$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
```

But it gives me this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*'

How can this be solved?

**EDIT**

I have also tried this code:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'password_hidden_on_stack_overflow'); // Add your own ck.pem passphrase here

foreach($deviceIDs as $deviceToken) {
    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    if (!$fp) exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default'
        );
    $payload = json_encode($body);

// Build & send notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

/*if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;*/
}   
// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

But it gives me this error: Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out)

Answer (score -1):

Not used this before, but I know a friend of mine used some open source code. Here is a link to it, hope it helps: [php-apn](http://libcapn.org/php-apn/)

Comment: which port does this php-apn uses?